# Create select from a hash key/value pair combination

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have key-value pairs in my model, and I would like to create an option-select from them. It's storing the "C" for "Child" and "S" for "Spouse" etc.

I'm open to refactoring if there is a better way, but would like to stick to the ABBR values being stored just because I'm a horrible speller.

My model:

```
class Identity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person, polymorphic: true

  RELATIONSHIP = {"M" => "Member", "S" => "Spouse", "C" => "Child", "DP" => "Domestic Partner"}     
end
```

My goal in the form is to output something like this:

```
<select name="relationship">
   <option value="M">Member</option>
   <option value="S">Spouse</option>
</select>
```

I would prefer that they always come out in a certain order, so I may be not going about this correct at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invert your hash first in your controller:

```
@inverted_relationships = Identity::RELATIONSHIP.invert
```

Then, you can make those available in your template using the `select_tag` forms helper:

```
<%= select_tag 'relationship', options_for_select(@inverted_relationships) %>
```

This should generate:

```
<select name="relationship">
    <option value="M">Member</option>
    <option value="S">Spouse</option>
    etc.
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your template.

```
select_tag 'relationship', options_for_select(@relationships.collect{ |k,v| [k, v] })
```

where @relationships is the hash you'll pass to your template from controller OR you can use Identity::RELATIONSHIP.collect { |k,v| [k, v] }